# Custom Data Validation | 1004 error on formula | regional settings | runs when stepped into code F8 or subsequent F5

Tags: excel, vba, validation, excel-formula, runtime-error

I am looping through cells and deleting existing Data-validation and adding new Custom data-validation. It works correctly in Eng-US, but shoots a 1004 error on `.Add` when I change my Regional format settings to Polish (Poland).

For 1st loop iteration, it works, but for subsequent loop iterations, it fails with the error. However, if I step into code (F8) or press (F5) again, it runs the loop iteration, but again gets stuck when processing next the cell.

```
For each Cell in Rng
    Cell.select

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete

        sValidationReplacement = sFormula
        sValidationReplacement = arrRow(giCOL_FORMULA_1)
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=sValidationReplacement

        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next Cell
```

Note: sFormula contains

```
=IF(AND($H11="H",K11>=1,ISNUMBER(K11)),TRUE,IF(AND($H11<>"H",K11>=0,ISNUMBER(K11)),TRUE,FALSE))
```

and original data-validation before delete is also the same. It is just being re-applied after evaluating value in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

In the Polish regional settings for Excel, I believe the argument separator is the semicolon, and not comma. Since your formula is a string, it seems relevant. I would try replacing all commas in the formula, like this:

```
=IF(AND($H11="H";K11>=1;ISNUMBER(K11));TRUE;IF(AND($H11<>"H";K11>=0;ISNUMBER(K11));TRUE;FALSE))
```

Comment: i have tried that. but the issue is dynamic validation via code only accepts Eng-US format i.e. commas. Later i think it converts the formula internally into the Polish format i.e. semi-colons.